# What should go in my my.cnf file

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Followed http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard to the T.

Log:

110313 20:48:37 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/var/moneymake-computer.local.pid ended
110313 20:48:46 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/var
110313 20:48:46 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/var/ is case insensitive
110313 20:48:46  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
110313 20:48:46 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
110313 20:48:46 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
110313 20:48:46 [ERROR] Aborting

110313 20:48:46  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
110313 20:48:47  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
110313 20:48:47 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

110313 20:48:47 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/var/moneymake-computer.local.pid ended
110313 20:48:56 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/var
110313 20:48:56 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/var/ is case insensitive
110313 20:48:56  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
110313 20:48:56 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
110313 20:48:56 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
110313 20:48:56 [ERROR] Aborting

110313 20:48:56  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
110313 20:48:58  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
110313 20:48:58 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

110313 20:48:58 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/var/moneymake-computer.local.pid ended

CONSOLE.app 
Shows tmp/mysql.sock Permission denied and that its starting and stopping the server every 10 seconds, which it looks like tmp/mysql.sock is being created every 10 seconds. Maybe that file is locked?

24 hours in so far....

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons this could be the case.  Can you verify that MySQL is actually running?  Even if it is, you might check the logs to see if it had any problems starting up or opening the socket.

Comment: You might check the Permissions on /tmp, I think it's owned by root:wheel by default, so mysql (running as the mysql user according to the launchd plist) might not have permissions to create the socket.

You might also have multiple mysql processes running (or at least something else bound to port 3306).  Try killing any mysqld processes in activity monitor before relaunching.

Comment: Did it but nothing helped.

Comment: if all else fails, you might try removing the launchd plist you added and then reinstall with [macports](http://www.macports.org/) -- that's typically how I install such dependencies on my OSX systems

Comment: Tried install everything with macports and same thing mysql is starting and stopping every 10 seconds.  It shows in the console that access to tmp/mysql.sock is Permission denied.  I tried to run the chown to make tmp read+write but not sure if mysql.sock is read write as, not sure you can since it created everytime mysql starts?